# Decompose $SO(8)$ and $Spin(8)$ 8 dimensional representations to $SO(m)$ and $SO(n)$

Tags: group-theory, differential-geometry, representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

We know that the $SO(8)$'s vector representation is 8 dimensional $8_v$, and $Spin(8)$ has the spinor representation  $8_s$ and its conjugate representation spinor $8_c$ . Together $8_v$, $8_c$ and $8_s$ form the triality.

Naively, I expect that the decomposition $SO(8)$ (or $Spin(8)$) of the $8_c$ and $8_s$ are conjugate with each other.

However from Lie Art mathematica file, I learned that

$SO(8)$ decomposes as $SO(5)$ and $SO(3)$:
$$
8_v=(4,2), \quad 8_c=(4,2), \quad 8_s=(1,3)+(5,1),
$$

- STRANGELY, $8_v$ and $8_c$ have the similar form, are they conjugate with each other? But $8_c$ and $8_s$ do not seem to conjugate with each other. Can you illuminate why?

$SO(8)$ decomposes as $SO(6)$ and $SO(2)$:
$$
8_v=\bar{4} \text{(-1)}+4 \text{(1)}, \quad 8_c=6 \text{(0)}+1 \text{(-2)}+1 \text{(2)}, \quad 8_s=\bar{4} \text{(1)}+4 \text{(-1)},
$$

- STRANGELY, $8_v$ and $8_s$ have the similar form, are they conjugate with each other? But $8_c$ and $8_s$ do not seem to conjugate with each other. Can you illuminate why?

---

My result is obtained from the Mathematica Lie Art code:

DecomposeIrrep[Irrep[D][1, 0, 0, 0], ProductAlgebra[Sp4, SU2]]

DecomposeIrrep[Irrep[D][0, 1, 0, 0], ProductAlgebra[Sp4, SU2]]

DecomposeIrrep[Irrep[D][0, 0, 1, 0], ProductAlgebra[Sp4, SU2]]

DecomposeIrrep[Irrep[D][0, 0, 0, 1], ProductAlgebra[Sp4, SU2]]

DecomposeIrrep[Irrep[D][1, 0, 0, 0], ProductAlgebra[SU4, U1]]

DecomposeIrrep[Irrep[D][0, 1, 0, 0], ProductAlgebra[SU4, U1]]

DecomposeIrrep[Irrep[D][0, 0, 1, 0], ProductAlgebra[SU4, U1]]

DecomposeIrrep[Irrep[D][0, 0, 0, 1], ProductAlgebra[SU4, U1]]

Answer (score 2):

There is an automorphism group of $\mathtt{D}_4$ that permutes these three $8$-dimensional modules. But if the subgroup you are restricting to is not normalized by this automorphism, there's no need for the modules to have similar-looking restrictions. Indeed, restricting to the $\mathtt{A}_1$ in the centre of the Dynkin diagram will produce similar decompositions.

Your $\mathtt{B}_3$ is stable under a subgroup of order $2$ of the $S_3$ of automorphisms, so two will behave the same and one (likely) will behave differently.

Notice that $\mathtt{B}_3$ is not well-defined. You have three options for the $\mathtt{B}_3$, given its images under triality.

Comment: thanks voted up plus 1,  you meant "an automorphism group of 4 " or "S3"? The 4 is of dihedral group order of how many elements? 4 or 8?

Comment: @anniemarieheart I mean $D_4$ as in Lie type $D_4$, i.e., $8$-dimensional orthogonal, and $B_3$ is $5$-dimensional orthogonal. The outer automorphism group of $D_4$, i.e., $\mathrm{Spin}(8)$, is isomorphic to $S_3$, but realized as genuine automorphisms you can only say that there is 'an' automorphism group, because of course there are lots of automorphisms with the same outer automorphirm image. I have edited the answer to make clear I'm not talking about $D_4$ but instead the algebraic group $D_4$, which is often denoted $\mathtt{D}_4$.

Comment: if 8v is a vector, 8s and 8c are spinors, and their triality rotats them, what makes the branch rule to have one of them differ from the other twos? I am confused what is special about one of the 8v, 8s and 8c?

Comment: SO(8) to SO(6) x SO(2) as SU4 x U1 chooses 8c special looking?

Comment: SO(8) to SO(5) x SO(3) as Sp4 x SU2 chooses 8s special l looking?

Comment: Two of the $8$s aren't even modules for $\mathrm{SO}(8)$. They are only modules for $\mathrm{Spin}$. There the $\mathrm{SO}$ you think of is just one of three that triality permutes. So your $\mathrm{SO}$ isn't special when you look from the $\mathrm{Spin}$ point of view.

Comment: yes I am looking at them as Spin(8) vector and spinor reps, but I still see one of them is special! ?

Comment: You might see that, but they aren't. There are three $\mathrm{SO}(8)$s inside the spin group, one for each $8$-dimensional module. So if you choose your subgroup to restrict to with respect to the one geometry, why should it be the same with respect to the other two?

Comment: I can accept your answer in 10 days if no better answers. But I am puzzled still can you see this https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3773876/141334 thanks!!!

Comment: I think you don't seem to understand what tirality means. It means that there is a homomorphism from $\mathrm{Spin}(8)$ to itself, whose cube is the identity. Consequently, it moves the subgroups of the spin group around. Your group $\mathrm{Spin}(6)$ doesn't exist. There are three of them, corresponding to the three $D_3$ subdiagrams of the $D_4$ Dynkin diagram. Choosing one chooses some orientation of the Dynkin diagram, and thus fixes one of the three $\mathrm{SO}(8)$ quotients of $\mathrm{Spin}(8)$.

Comment: anyway, please have a look at my new one, the main puzzle is actually in the second question in the link. Thank you please -