# (8) 8 dimensional representations and mutation

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, differential-geometry, representation-theory, lie-groups

Here is a follow up of on strange facts of $Spin(8)$ group [Decompose $SO(8)$ and $Spin(8)$ 8 dimensional representations to $SO(m)$ and $SO(n)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3773805/141334)

We know that the $Spin(8)$'s vector representation is 8 dimensional $8_v$, and $Spin(8)$ has the spinor representation  $8_s$ and its conjugate representation spinor $8_c$ . Together $8_v$, $8_c$ and $8_s$ form the triality.

Let us do $Spin(8)$ decomposes as $Spin(5)$ and $Spin(3)$:
$$
8_v=(4,2), \quad 8_c=(4,2), \quad 8_s=(1,3)+(5,1). \tag{a}
$$

$Spin(8)$ decomposes as $Spin(6)$ and $Spin(2)$:
$$
8_v=\bar{4} \text{(-1)}+4 \text{(1)}, \quad 8_c=6 \text{(0)}+1 \text{(-2)}+1 \text{(2)}, \quad 8_s=\bar{4} \text{(1)}+4 \text{(-1)}, \tag{b}
$$

- I seem to know $$8_v=(4,2)$$ in (a) is related to $$8_v=\bar{4} \text{(-1)}+4 \text{(1)}$$ in (b), simply that 4 and $\bar{4}$ in $Spin(6)$ become the same as 4   in $Spin(5)$.
- STRANGELY, $$8_c=(4,2)$$  in (a) seems NOT related to $$8_c=6 \text{(0)}+1 \text{(-2)}+1 \text{(2)}$$  in (b). Can you illuminate why? or how can they be related? (By restricting $Spin(6)$ to $Spin(5)$, etc?)
- STRANGELY, $$8_s=(1,3)+(5,1)$$  in (a) seems NOT related to $$8_s=\bar{4} \text{(1)}+4 \text{(-1)}$$  in (b). Can you illuminate why? or how can they be related? (By restricting $Spin(6)$ to $Spin(5)$, etc?)
- My main point is that it seems to be natural to have $8_c=(4,2)$ in (a)  related to $8_s=\bar{4} \text{(1)}+4 \text{(-1)}$  in (b). So $8_c$ from $Spin(5)\times Spin(3)$ mutates to $8_s$ from $Spin(6)\times Spin(2)$? Do we know a precise math formulation?
- My main point is that it seems to be natural to have $8_s=(1,3)+(5,1)$ in (a)  related to $8_c=6 \text{(0)}+1 \text{(-2)}+1 \text{(2)}$   in (b). So $8_s$ from $Spin(5)\times Spin(3)$ mutates to $8_c$ from $Spin(6)\times Spin(2)$? Do we know a precise math formulation?

Comment: Again, I keep telling you, you write $\mathrm{Spin}(6)$ as if it's a unique object. It isn't. There are three of them. There is no puzzle here. One of the $\mathrm{Spin}(6)$s behaves nicely with respect to one of the three $8$-dimensional modules, and the other two need not. Choose a different $\mathrm{Spin}(6)$, and a different $8$ works well.

Comment: thank you -- if you can write down the branching rules for the three Spin(6) and the branching rules for the three Spin(5) -- maybe I can fully understand and digest better !?

Comment: You've done it yourself. The three $\mathrm{Spin}(6)$s are permuted by the triality map. The three $8$s are permuted by the traility map. So the decomposition of one $8$ to the three different $\mathrm{Spin}(6)$s is the same as the decomposition of the three different $8$s to one of the $\mathrm{Spin}(6)$s.

Comment: Can I write instead as these?
$Spin(8)$ decomposes as $Spin(5)$ and $Spin(3)$:
$$
8_s=(4,2), \quad 8_c=(4,2), \quad 8_v=(1,3)+(5,1). \tag{a}
$$
$Spin(8)$ decomposes as $Spin(6)$ and $Spin(2)$:
$$
8_s=\bar{4} \text{(-1)}+4 \text{(1)}, \quad 8_c=\bar{4} \text{(1)}+4 \text{(-1)}, \quad 8_v=6 \text{(0)}+1 \text{(-2)}+1 \text{(2)}, \tag{b}
$$

Comment: @David A. Craven, and why do they write this way in https ://arxiv.org/abs/1912.10969 ?

Comment: It's easier to output on a computer? They are only dealing with small examples? In general, the number of irreducible modules of the same dimension is unbounded.

Comment: I do not understand fully what you said, their paper is based on Lie Art computer Mathematica code https://arxiv.org/abs/1912.10969 and it is exactly their output above puzzles me

Comment: see p.193 of it